# Percentages for different platform generation

Tags: xna, c#, mathematics, probability

I have a level manager, which creates levels and levels create platforms.

Levels can contain a variety of platforms.

I dont really understand how I can say:

> I want a 10% of one platform being made, 30% chance of another, and 70% chance for anotgher and so on...

At the moment I have a method that looks like this:

```
   private void creationManager(float moveChance, float breakableChance, float superJumpChance)
```

I'm not sure how I can use these values and probabaility to determine which type of paltform is created.

Any ideas?

Comment: And this is useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling

Answer (score 1):

Another possible algorithm. This is easily expandable as well and does not have to use % of 100:

```
//assuming rand() returns integers
#define numberOfPlatformTypes 3
int platform[numberOfPlatformTypes];
platform[0] = 10;
platform[1] = 30;
platform[2] = 70;

int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlatformTypes; ++i)
 total += platform[i];

int r = rand()%total;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlatformTypes; ++i)
{
 if(r < platform[i])
  return i;
 r -= platform[i];
}
```

Comment: if your rand() returns a float you can just do rand()*total instead. I am unsure what the values in your creationManager function represent so it's up to you to determine the chance for each type of platform to show up.

Comment: Where does `r` come in? How does it affect the result?

Comment: had a typo, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Use random numbers! :)
Here is a bit of pseudo code to get you started.

```
// Assuming rand() returns a value between 0 and 1.
float r = rand();

if(r <= 0.1f)
 /* create platform type 1 */
else if (r <= 0.3f)
 /* create platform type 2 */
else if (r <= 0.7f)
 /* create platform type 3 */
```

It is amazing what you can achieve with just random numbers.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this is doing the equivalent of 10%, 20%, and 40%...